# automatic word in color

Tags: macros

I would like some text to display in `red` color. For Example `paragraph` text need to display in `red` color. My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.

This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.

This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.

This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.

This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.This is the sample paragraph text here. This is the sample paragraph text here.
\end{document}
```

How do achieve this?

Comment: try `{\color{red} ... text...}` and `\usepackage{color}`

Comment: I would like `automatically` to display without using `color` package.

Comment: You mean, you want the word “automatically” to be displayed in red wherever it is found? (If so, why does that word not appear in your sample text?)

Comment: How does latex know which text to make red in color? In your MWE, which parts do you want to make red? what do you mean by `sample text`? Is the text to be made red in color always inside some environment or other wise marked by some command?

Comment: Are you asking how to render the string "paragraph" in red automatically? Or should a whole paragraph be rendered in red? It it's the latter, *which* one?

Comment: `"paragraph"` only need to display in `red` color and not whole paragraph text.

Comment: May be this helps you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575267/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-specific-terms-of-equation-for-exemple-p-for-a#575271

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use color `package` and you want to start automatic coloring then you can use `pdfcsplain` format with OPmac and no LaTeX:

```
\input opmac \localcolor

\def\registerword#1{\sdef{w:#1}{{\Red#1}}%
   \expandafter\mubyte\csname w:#1\endcsname \space#1\endmubyte}

\mubytein=0
\registerword { is }
\registerword {paragraph}
\registerword {text}
\mubytein=1

This is the sample paragraph text here. 
Other text is tested. How are you?
This is the sample paragraph text here. 
Other text is tested. How are you?

\bye
```

[image: colorword]

Comment: it's showing `compile error` `! Undefined control sequence.
\registerword #1->\sdef
                        {w:#1}{{\Red #1}}\expandafter \mubyte \csname w:#1\e...
l.5 \registerword { is }`

Comment: @Balaji Are you using pdfcsplain? What control sequence is undefined? Are you able to read this information from the log? Your log message is from another sample than my code, because line 5 is referred but line 5 in my code is empty.

Answer (score 1):

When I want part of my text be displayed in red, I usually put this macro in the preamble:

```
 \newcommand{\red}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
```

and in the text I use:

```
Some normal (black) text \red{the part of the text that I want to be red} some other text.
```

Comment: Anyway  `\usepackage{color}` is needed

Comment: that is good. But it is not automatic. Wherever sample word comes I have to add \red{sample} so as to make the word in red. This is not asked for.

Comment: @Olga K I'd rather use `\usepackage{xcolor}`

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}

    This is the sample \verb!!\textcolor{red}{paragraph}\verb!! text here.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does not answer the OP, since it does not provide something automatic.

Comment: What is the purpose of `\verb!!` here? As I understand it the first `!` starts the verbatim and the second `!` immediately ends it. It seems to do nothing

Comment: !! At the start and at the end provides additional benefits of activating the colored text option inside verbatim while ! at the start and at the end only actuates verbatim.