# How can I change the color of specific terms of equation (For exemple $P$) for all the text?

Tags: beamer, math-mode, equations, color

Like, to always that I put `$P$` in the latex code, it appears with the color purple)
This is the code: (Look that I need to put `\purple{$Q$}` <= that is a shortcut for `\textcolor{purple}{$Q$}`. Maybe there is a way to fix this command for every time that I type `$P$`. Please help! Thanks for the attention.

```
\begin{itemize}
\item \justifying \textbf{\purple{$\Rightarrow$: $(P \Rightarrow Q) \Rightarrow $}\purple{($P \rightarrow Q$ \textcolor{black}{tautológica})}: Se \purple{$P$} \blue{implica logicamente} \purple{$Q$}, por definição, \purple{$Q$} é \blue{verdadeira} todas as vezes que \purple{$P$} é \blue{verdadeira}. Assim, os valores lógicos das proposições \purple{$P$} e \purple{$Q$} não podem ser simultaneamente e respectivamente \blue{$V$} e \blue{$F$}. Logo, a coluna resultante da tabela de verdade da condicional \purple{$P \rightarrow Q$} tem somente o valor \blue{$V$}. Logo, por definição, se \purple{$P$} então \purple{$Q$} é tautológica.}
    \item \justifying \textbf{\purple{$\Leftarrow$}: \purple{($P \rightarrow Q$ \textcolor{black}{tautológica})$\Rightarrow$($P \Rightarrow Q$)} Reciprocamente, se \purple{$P$} então \purple{$Q$} é tautológica, a coluna resultante da sua tabela de verdade tem somente valor \blue{$V$}. Então não ocorre que os valores lógicos das proposições \purple{$P$} e \purple{$Q$} sejam simultaneamente e respectivamente \blue{$V$} e \blue{$F$}. Logo, por definição, \purple{$P$} implica logicamente \purple{$Q$}.}
\end{itemize}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't advocate doing it the way you request (see **SUPPLEMENT** for alternative), but I try to provide it anyway.  Here, I have an environment `pitemize` in which *literal* instances of `$P$` and `$Q$` are replaced with their purple counterparts.  Any other instance involving other characters (even in conjunction with `P` and `Q`) still have to specified with the `\purple` invocation.  Obviously, blue invocations are also not addressed here.

Lastly, this will only function properly if `$P$` and `$Q$` are in the top level group.  Thus, I had to change your invocations of `\textbf{...}` to `\bfseries`, so that the `$P$` and `$Q$` would appear in the top level group of the environment.

It is not clear from your question if this approach is sufficient for your needs.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor,listofitems,environ}
\NewEnviron{pitemize}{%
  \setsepchar{$P$||$Q$}%
  \readlist\Myenv{\BODY}%
  \begin{itemize}
  \foreachitem\z\in\Myenv[]{%
    \ifnum\zcnt=1\relax\else\textcolor{purple}{\Myenvsep[\zcnt-1]}\fi
    \z
  }%
  \end{itemize}
}
\newcommand\purple[1]{\textcolor{purple}{#1}}
\newcommand\blue[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\def\justifying{}
\begin{document}
\begin{pitemize}
\item \justifying \bfseries\purple{$\Rightarrow$: $(P \Rightarrow Q) \Rightarrow $}\purple{($P \rightarrow Q$ \textcolor{black}{tautológica})}: Se $P$ \blue{implica logicamente} $Q$, por definição, $Q$ é \blue{verdadeira} todas as vezes que $P$ é \blue{verdadeira}. Assim, os valores lógicos das proposições $P$ e $Q$ não podem ser simultaneamente e respectivamente \blue{$V$} e \blue{$F$}. Logo, a coluna resultante da tabela de verdade da condicional \purple{$P \rightarrow Q$} tem somente o valor \blue{$V$}. Logo, por definição, se $P$ então $Q$ é tautológica.
    \item \justifying \bfseries\purple{$\Leftarrow$}: \purple{($P \rightarrow Q$ \textcolor{black}{tautológica})$\Rightarrow$($P \Rightarrow Q$)} Reciprocamente, se $P$ então $Q$ é tautológica, a coluna resultante da sua tabela de verdade tem somente valor \blue{$V$}. Então não ocorre que os valores lógicos das proposições $P$ e $Q$ sejam simultaneamente e respectivamente \blue{$V$} e \blue{$F$}. Logo, por definição, $P$ implica logicamente $Q$.
\end{pitemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**SUPPLEMENT**

I think a preferable method would be the use of active characters to turn on and off various colors.  Here I use `!` delimiters for math-mode purple and `?` delimiters for text-mode blue.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\justifying{}
{
\catcode`!=\active\gdef!#1!{\textcolor{purple}{$#1$}}
\catcode`?=\active\gdef?#1?{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
}
\newenvironment{pitemize}
{\catcode`!=\active\catcode`?=\active\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}}
\begin{document}
\begin{pitemize}
\item \justifying \textbf{!\Rightarrow$: $(P \Rightarrow Q) \Rightarrow (P \rightarrow Q! tautológica!)!: Se !P! ?implica logicamente? !Q!, por definição, !Q! é ?verdadeira? todas as vezes que !P! é ?verdadeira?. Assim, os valores lógicos das proposições !P! e !Q! não podem ser simultaneamente e respectivamente ?$V$? e ?$F$?. Logo, a coluna resultante da tabela de verdade da condicional !P \rightarrow Q! tem somente o valor ?$V$?. Logo, por definição, se !P! então !Q! é tautológica.}
    \item \justifying \textbf{!\Leftarrow!: !(P \rightarrow Q! tautológica!)\Rightarrow(P \Rightarrow Q)! Reciprocamente, se !P! então !Q! é tautológica, a coluna resultante da sua tabela de verdade tem somente valor ?$V$?. Então não ocorre que os valores lógicos das proposições !P! e !Q! sejam simultaneamente e respectivamente ?$V$? e ?$F$?. Logo, por definição, !P! implica logicamente !Q!.}
\end{pitemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Really an awesome suggestion....Salute....

Comment: Thak u very much! The answer was very helpfull!

Comment: @LuccaAbbadoNeres You are welcome.  If my answer "solves" your problem better than any of the answers offered (in this case there are none others offered), you can consider clicking the check mark next to my answer to "accept" it.  This will signify to readers which of the several answers best addresses the issue that you posed.  If you are still looking for a better answer, then you need do nothing more, and others may try to take a stab at a better or different approach.